# Passing values from text boxes to class

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to call a method in a class from my main form.

In my main form on click (save button). I want to take the values from the text boxes and then assign to them to my get set properties in my class:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ticket.Details td = new ticket.Details();

    txtRef.Text = td.@ref;
    txtSubject.Text = td.subject;
    txtContact_Name.Text = td.contact_name;
    txtCompany_Name.Text = td.company_name;
    rtDescription.Text = td.description;
    rtBusiness_Impact.Text = td.business_impact;
    txtSeverity.Text = td.severity;

}
```

As part of the above code, I also want to hit the method called,

```
public int AddTicket(Details details)
        {
            const string query = "INSERT INTO support.....
```

I want to hit my "AddTicket" section so that it will hit the ExecuteWrite section in that method.

How do I expose that method so that I can say, ~add ticket? therefore hitting my SQL Lite DB and inserting the row?

Comment: Hey, what exactly have you tried to invoke the method and where are you stuck, you just need to call `AddTicket(td);` like this. I would only be able to tell for sure if you tell me the name of class `AddTicket` is part of and button1_click is part and etc. More the info to recreate/understand, the merrier :)

Comment: I cant do AddTicket(td); because it does not know where to find AddTicket. My class is called Ticket, even if i write Ticket.AddTicket(td) it does not show.

Comment: check if your ticket class is `public` then you need to instantiate the class like `var ticket = new Ticket();` then `ticket.AddTicket(td);`